# What is the python-jenkins wrapper commands for cancelling queued build and rebuild a previous build?

Tags: python, jenkins, google-api-python-client

I am using **python-jenkins** wrapper to operate on Jenkins jobs from my python project. Most of the operations like building a job, deleting the build and so on have a python command in the documentation, but there is no such command available for **rebuilding an old build using python as backend**, can someone pls suggest the piece of code for it that I can use?

Another issue is with the cancel_queue() api of python-jenkins package, it takes a job id as a parameter, where can I find that id?

```
    def cancel_queue(self, id):
        '''Cancel a queued build.

        :param id: Jenkins job id number for the build, ``int``
        '''
        # Jenkins seems to always return a 404 when using this REST endpoint
        # https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21311
        try:
            self.jenkins_open(
                requests.Request(
                    'POST', self._build_url(CANCEL_QUEUE, locals()),
                    headers={'Referer': self.server}))
        except NotFoundException:
            # Exception is expected; cancel_queue() is a best-effort
            # mechanism, so ignore it
            pass
```

this is the code for the cancel_queue api, which id is this? **Is there any other way to cancel the builds which are present in the queue at a time?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I learnt this the hard-way, Jenkins has its own queue_id which we can read it using python-jenkins wrapper.
For example:

```
server = jenkins.Jenkins(URL, username=USER, password=PASSWORD)
queue_id = server.get_build_info(job_name, build_no)['queueId']
```